# Select hour 60 minutes before Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Do I need to select that returns me the records where the time field is at least in the next 60 minutes.

example:

```
table
time = '05: 30: 00 '
time = '04: 30: 00 '
time = '03: 30: 00 '
time = '06: 30: 00 '
```

If I consult 05:00:00 should return the records

```
time = '05: 30: 00 'and
time = '06: 30: 00 '
```

. I searched but only found between hours.

Answer (score 1):

To select records with a time value in the next hour:

```
select * from yourtable where time between now() and now() + '1 hour'::interval;
```